# Unindexed remote maven repositories in IntelliJ IDEA 14

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I've imported an existing Gradle project to IntelliJ IDEA. I keep getting a notification:

[image: Notification text]

> Unindexed remote maven repositories found. **Disable...**
>
> The following repositories used in your gradle projects were not indexed yet: 
>            http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
>
> If you want to use dependency completion for these repositories artifacts,
>            **Open Repositories List**, select required repositories and press "Update" button (**show balloon**)

So, I've opened the Repositories List and as you might imagine there is *http://repo1.maven.org/maven2* with the Type=Remote and Updated=Never. The problem is, when I click on the **Update** button, IDEA takes a few minutes and then reports an error.

[image: Error after update]

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
org.codehaus.plexus.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException:
java.util.NoSuchElementException

role: org.apache.maven.execution.MavenExecutionRequestPopulator
roleHint:
```

What should I do now? How can I solve this problem? I'm not looking for a way to disable notifications for this. Restarting IDEA doesn't help, trying to Update the repository index fails immediately after the next attempt.

Answer (score 8):

This is a known bug:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-102693

There is zip file with a patch attached to the bug, and as far as I see it will soon be included as a official patch for version 14.1.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same problem but the other answers didn't help in anyway.

The problem was the `mavenCentral()` commands in my `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

**The solution was to replace `mavenCentral()` with the following lines:**

```
maven {
    url("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Problem caused after idea update. Maven settings resets to bundled version. Solution for that problem is in setting of maven version to latest version.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I set the Maven home directory to /opt/maven under File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @osexp2003, I deleted my `repository` folder under `.m2` and restart intellij.

IntelliJ -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Repositories -> selected `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2` and clicked on `update` in the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem, solved by it changing maven home in IntelliJ. In IntelliJ go to:

```
File-> Setting-> Build, Execution, Deployment-> Build Tools->Maven
```

Change Maven Home Directory from bundled to local installed. for me the option available was:

```
/usr/share/maven
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. 
My experience is deleting ~/.gradle dir will work fine, no more warning again.

I think this is because the ~/.gradle dir is first used by my Eclipse(Spring Tool Suite), so the files inside there are not registered in IDEA's internal index db, so cause the warning.

Here is what i'v done:

First, i chose "Open Repositories List", then click update in the dialog,
then it will take too long time to complete the action.
Then i checked the ~/.gradle, it's very big, it even contains android sdk related jars, this is why it's so slow.

So, i deleted ~/.gradle, then reopen IDEA, no more warning again.
I checked ~/.gradle again, it only contains my dependency jars.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `mavencentral()` to `jcenter()` fixed this problem for me using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.