# Intellij IDEA 15: Unindexed remote maven repositories found

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I created a Java Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3. But I am getting the following error.

```
Unindexed remote maven repositories found. Disable...
        The following repositories used in your gradle projects were not indexed yet: 
        http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
        If you want to use dependency completion for these repositories artifacts,
        Open Repositories List, select required repositories and press "Update" button (show balloon)
```

When I open the repositories list and click update, I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Transfer for nexus-maven-repository-index.properties failed
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij Community can't use http proxy for Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784132/intellij-community-cant-use-http-proxy-for-maven)

Comment: I had the same problem and wrote an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037082/unindexed-remote-maven-repositories-in-intellij-idea-14

Answer (score 7):

In your build.gradle repositories section replace mavencentral() with another mirror, like so:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://uk.maven.org/maven2"
    }
}
```

then when you get the "Unindexed remote maven repositories found" go to the repositories view and press update. that should do it

Comment: does not help at all. -1

Comment: obviously it helped other people, so probably you didn't have the same issue

Comment: helped me. thanks a lot ! but why does this work ? some issue related to proxies im assuming

Answer (score 5):

A possible (though not the only cause for this issue is, that you are behind a firewall that is blocking your connection). In this case you may need to configure a proxy server for Maven.

In my case it helped to just create a new file named `settings.xml` with the following contents and place it under `C:\Users\<username>\.m2\` (or `~/.m2` on linux):

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>HTTP proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>REPLACE_BY_IP_OR_HOSTNAME</host>
      <port>REPLACE_BY_PORT_NUMBER</port>
    </proxy>

    <proxy>
      <id>HTTPS proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>REPLACE_BY_IP_OR_HOSTNAME</host>
      <port>REPLACE_BY_PORT_NUMBER</port>
    </proxy>
 </proxies>
</settings>
```

Replace host and port for your specific environment.

Comment: Thank you! This was the ticket for me! Also, the full reference for the proxy settings is here: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: @lanoxx where can i find HOSTNAME & PORT_NUMBER required

Comment: If you are behind a proxy, for example because you are in a corporate environment, a school, a university, etc., then you would usually get this information from your organization or the local IT department, there are also way to discover this from your PC's proxy configuration if you know where to look for (there are already other SO answers which discuss that).

Answer (score 1):

Adding proxy settings to VM options worked. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26483623/2626981) helped me to set the proxy settings on IntelliJ for Maven