# IntelliJ: Authorization exception when updating Maven repository index

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gradle, authorization

When I try to update the Maven repository in my project I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:java.io.IOException: Authorization Exception retrieving nexus.-maven-repository-index.properties
```

I looked at similar questions asked before and one of solutions is to disable the option to use Maven 3, however, that is no longer an available option on the current IntelliJ. Any other ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall that may be blocking your connection to Maven repository? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43500734/2748747

Comment: @BrandonWhite I added the proxy settings but I continue to get the Authorization Exception.